# recompiling PHP

Tags: php, recompile

I have compiled php with some optional extensions like APC (for caching),APD (for debugging) and other vital extensions. Now I need to install another extension called mhash (for encryption) and my question is that: 
Do i need to recompile php from scratch including the previous extensions and the last one or it is possible to recompile php just with last one (hopefully the previous extensions still supported)??

Comment: I guess the make install would take care about..and i need to recompile php with last one only!!

Answer (score 1):

The other compiled extensions will still work.